# How to find start and end indices in python dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

My code-

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    thisdict =  {
    row['house']:  "Holding_number"}
print(thisdict)
```

Result- `{'House 193/A': 'Holding_number'}`
Expected output - `{'House 193/A': 0,10 'Holding_number'}`
I want to add start and end indices.
Dataframe-
[image]

Comment: What's the original dataframe? please add it into your question.

Comment: `{'House 193/A': 0,10 'Holding_number'}` is not a valid syntax

Comment: This is my expected output in spacy format. I have added the dataframe

Comment: @bellatrix What does 0, 10 mean?

Comment: Start and end indices of "House 193/A". Starts from 0 and ends at 10

Comment: Python dictionary doesn't have indices, it only has keys and their associated value. Did you mean dataframe?

Comment: Do you mean the string length?

Comment: If it's dataframe, the start index will always be 0, while the end index will be `df.shape[0] - 1`

Comment: Yes. I was looking for the string length of row['house']

Comment: Do you want a tuple as output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean by?

```
lod = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    lod.append({row['house']:  f"(0, {len(row['house']) - 1}) {row['label1']}"})
print(lod)
```

Comment: [{'House 263': (0, 8)}, {'House 31': (0, 7)}, {'House 193/A': (0, 10)}] it prints like this. But I want to add label1 column with it. Expected output - {'House 193/A': 0,10 'Holding_number'}

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
thisdict  = {
    row['house']: (0, len(row['house']-1, row['label1'])
    i, row in df.iterrows()
}
```